# Hi can someone help me in creating a quartz expression which triggers every 120 min 7 days a week?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Hi can someone help me in creating a quartz expression which triggers every 120 min 7 days a week?I tried something like `<0 0/120 * * * ?* MON-SUN>`

but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Minutes go up to 60 so you can't have an interval of 120. 120 minutes is two hours so you want

```
0 0 0/2 * * ?
```